# How to find MAX V CPLD pinout

Tags: intel-fpga, programmable-logic

Can someone please explain how to find the pin-out of a 5M80Z CPLD device. 
The documentation on this page shows the names of the pins but does not indicate the pin numbers.

I have not encountered this naming scheme before:
http://www.altera.com/literature/lit-dp.jsp?category=MAX%205

Also I do not have ORCAD installed so using the .obj files is out of the question.

EDIT:

I just installed the demo version of ORCAD and I see this which is completely confusing:

[image]

So which is true now, the rightmost column on the pdf or the .olb file

Comment: It looks to me as though the pin numbers are the right-most column, what's the package for the device? That scheme is common with BGA packages and possibly others.

Comment: The package is TQFP-64 and the device is 5M80ZE64C5N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 5M80ZE64C5N if you look at [Pin Information for the MAXV 5M80Z Device](http://www.altera.com/literature/dp/max-v/5M80Z.pdf) and scroll down to page 3 you'll see the pin numbers for the E64 devices in the right-most column.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this , just to make sure is M64 the same as E64, both are TQFP-64

Comment: It looks like the M64 is a BGA so the different numering scheme makes sense: http://uk.farnell.com/altera/5m80zm64c5n/cpld-max-v-80-le-64mbga/dp/2100807

Comment: I was looking for the pinout of the TQFP-64 part. How do I make sure that A1 is pin 1 and and B1 is pin2.

Comment: The A1 etc is for the BGA part, if you look at page 3 onwards where it says E64 you'll see the numbers are between 1 and 64.